# Might & Magic VII: What's the point of a bank?

Tags: might-and-magic-7-blood-and-honor

Why would I ever want to use a bank in *Might & Magic VII*? Is it only helpful in the case where your whole party dies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Remember, in this case, you'll cheat the death once again. Or if that fails, I guess you'll be leaving your money to children or something.

:]

Comment: Ah right, hehe. I guess I abuse saving&loading as if something too terrible happens I just load and avoid doing that..

Comment: @Claudiu Also, I heard that banks could be raided under some circumstances. Don't know if the money could be recovered or not. Imagine what kind of choice would it be if playing without loading earlier saves - to risk losing money when dying or to risk losing them from the bank.

Comment: yeah i definitely have to re-play the game (or start over) without loading saves. it would be a far different game..